# Remove all occurrences of strings from list

Tags: python

Someone please tell me there is a cleaner way to write this!? I want to remove all instances of 'Features & Benefits'. There must be a cleaner way to do this for strings in a list.

```
lov_headers = [x.find('displayname').text for x in soup.find_all('attributedefinition')]


if 'Part number' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Part number')
if 'Product Features' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Product Features')
if 'Packaging' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Packaging')
if 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
if 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
if 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
if 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
if 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
if 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
if 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
if 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
if 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
if 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
if 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
```

Comment: ...please learn about loops.

Comment: `[x for x in lov_headers if x != 'Features & Benefits']`

Answer (score 1):

Put what you want to remove into a `set()`, then use a list comprehension to filter out the results that you don't want:

```
to_remove = set(['Part number', 'Features & Benefits', 'Product Features', 'Packaging'])

new_list = [i for i in lov_headers if i not in to_remove]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
while 'Features & Benefits' in lov_headers:
    lov_headers.remove('Features & Benefits')
```

Comment: The time complexity on this is not good at all.

Comment: Agree. But if the OP wants to remove few select headers, the time complexity does not matter. Downloading the document would take way more time than searching through a list.